# Syntax error in helper data trying to assign a model to a outside variable

Tags: magento-1.9, helper

```
class Custom_Catalog_Helper_Data extends Mage_Catalog_Helper_Data
{
    private $promo = Mage::getModel('module/promo')->load(1);
    public function test(){
       // this function uses $promo
    }
}
```

I'm not that *aware of syntax's in magento* and i tried doing like this because my test function gets called many times and each time i don't want to create a new model object instead use the same existing one. (Something like singleton) If this is not the proper way how can i achieve it.

When the data class loads i need the model object to be assigned as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Custom_Catalog_Helper_Data extends Mage_Catalog_Helper_Data
{
    protected $_promo = null;

    protected function _getPromo()
    {
        if ($this->_promo === null) {
            $this->_promo = Mage::getModel('module/promo')->load(1);
        }
        return $this->_promo;
    }

    public function test()
    {
        $promo = $this->_getPromo();
        // this function uses $promo
    }
}
```

Comment: Or just Mage::getSingleton instead of getModel would achieve the same result